# Can you downsample an image from a websocket prior to rendering

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I have an app that is pulling in images through a websocket roughly a few times per second from a server. There is a significant load on the app and the images sometimes skip renderings.

The images themselves are of a much higher resolution than necessary and downsampling them prior to render would help a lot. Is that possible?

Here is the websocket code:

```
const ws = new WebSocket(config.videoWebSocketURL);
<img className={styles.img} src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${data}`} />
```

Any other ideals to speed up rendering are welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to do live video streaming from still images (from a webcam or video source)?  I've been down this route several times - it doesn't scale.  What's generating these frames?

Comment: Images. It's not to scale or for commercial use. It's a proof of concept

Comment: What I mean by "it doesn't scale" is that it's nearly impossible to stream large JPEG images in real time.  The img tag itself will scale the image down for you.  But I suspect the real problem is on the server side - where you are shoving frames into the socket faster than your web app can consume.  Can you downsample on the server side?

Comment: Also, all of this is conjecture, because you are providing very few details of your architecture.

Comment: If your app is already having a hard time handling the large images, wouldn't adding a downsampling process to it just impare it further? This should be done server side if possible.

Answer (score 1):

> pulling in images through a websocket roughly a few times per second

You are setting yourself on a road of pain.

Use correct protocol and interfaces which were meant to show animated content: HTTP + `<video>` tag.

If I had a bunch of jpeg files as source, I would convert them server-side (prior to sending) into video. Then I would send stream directly to a html5 `video` tag. This solves many problems, for example backpressure and buffering issues, frame skipping, etc.

For conversion possible solution could be to use ffmpeg, example:

`ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i frame-%d.jpg output.mp4`

---

If you *really* want to do this rendering manually in the browser,
then possible directions to explore would be:

- using [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) and [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) API – canvas works in [immediate graphics mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics)), it can render potentially up to 60 frames per second;
- using [createImageBitmap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) for image manipulation (note: downsampling and resizing is not cross-browser compatible yet);
- using web workers and [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) object, which could [potentially speed up operations](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/offscreen-canvas) (note: this is experimental feature).

**Demo**

**Before you run it, put some images named `frame-0.jpeg` to `frame-6.jpeg` alongside this app files.**

- I have used images of faces generated from https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com/, which are 1024x1024 pixels.
- It is not implemented using React intentionally, to see how fast minimal solution would be.

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "images-on-canvas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-ws": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

*app.js*

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = require('express')()
require('express-ws')(app)

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')))
app.ws('/', async function (socket) {
  // send frame files 0 to 6
  for (let i = 0, count = 6; i <= count; i += 1) {
    try {
      let data = await fs.promises.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, `frame-${i}.jpeg`))
      socket.send(data)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rendering Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var cv = document.getElementById('mycanvas')
      var ctx = cv.getContext('2d')
      var ws = new WebSocket(location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws'))
      var sprites = []

      ws.onmessage = function onMessage(event) {
        // NOTE: check compatibility for options object, works in Chrome 52+
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap#browser_compatibility
        var opts = {
          resizeWidth: 200,
          resizeHeight: 200,
          resizeQuality: 'pixelated'
        }
        createImageBitmap(event.data, 0, 0, 1024, 1024, opts).then(function (sprite) {
          sprites.push(sprite)
        })

        // NOTE: classic way to draw on canvas
        // var img = new Image()
        // img.addEventListener('load', function onLoad(event) {
        //   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
        //   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
        // })
        // img.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data)
      }

      function draw(high_res_timestamp) {
        if (sprites.length) {
          console.log(high_res_timestamp)
          var sprite = sprites.shift()
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
          ctx.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(draw)
      }
      draw()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Having written all that, I really think the better approach would be to do this server-side, as I written above.

Why? You have predictable output and serving video is a solved problem. This way you avoid all the headache with using experimental, or not well-supported APIs, and probably will have much less code to write, test and maintain.

Comment: Interesting. This is exactly what I was thinking. I am not sure why it was originally done the way it was. There are reasons why the code on the server needs specific images, but no reason as to why we have to show it that way in the browser.

Comment: The project is done in React and I am putting a class component in place to limit the renders to once or twice a second. I am hoping that this keeps the overhead to a minimum.

Comment: I've updated my answer exploring client-side rendering, maybe it helps!